# Multiple notification wrong content on click android

Tags: android, notifications

I receive multiple notification successfully using the notification intent below. But when i click on any notification it opened the last notification received everytime. can someone tell me how to open corresponding notification. i means each notification has its own content.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    /*
     *      Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
            ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GCMIntentService.class.getName());
            Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
            startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
            setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
     *
     */


    GCMNotificationUtility.notiMsg = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
    GCMNotificationUtility.notPubDate = chopJson(intent.getStringExtra("datepublished"));
    GCMNotificationUtility.notDescription =chopJson(intent.getStringExtra("description"));
    GCMNotificationUtility.notLink = chopJson(intent.getStringExtra("news_url"));
    GCMNotificationUtility.notCategory= chopJson(intent.getStringExtra("category"));



    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher; // icon from resources
    CharSequence tickerText =context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);//intent.getStringExtra("me"); // ticker-text

    long when = System.currentTimeMillis(); // notification time
    CharSequence xmsg =GCMNotificationUtility.notiMsg;


    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);


    System.out.println("nodescription "+GCMNotificationUtility.notDescription);

    ActusNewActivity.description=GCMNotificationUtility.notDescription;
    ActusNewActivity.pudDate=GCMNotificationUtility.notPubDate;
    ActusNewActivity.Link=GCMNotificationUtility.notLink;
    ActusNewActivity.title=GCMNotificationUtility.notiMsg;

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,ActusNewActivity.class);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 

    int unique_id = (int) c.getTimeInMillis();

    //set calendar.getTimeInMillis() as  unique ID.
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, unique_id , notificationIntent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context,tickerText,xmsg, pendingIntent);
    notification.flags|=notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND|Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    notification.vibrate=new long[] {100L, 100L, 200L, 500L};
    notificationManager.notify(unique_id, notification);

    GCMNotificationUtility.notificationReceived=true;
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
    wl.acquire();       

}


public String chopJson(String y){

    String x = ":\"";
    int xval = y.indexOf(x)+2;

    String substring = y.substring(0, xval);
    String newElement =  y.replace(substring, "");
    int lastvalue = newElement.length()-2;
    String value = newElement.substring(0,lastvalue);

    return value;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of :

`notificationManager.notify(unique_id, notification);`

use

```
notificationManager.notify((int) when , notification);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: :-) Please accept the answer if it was helpful to you so that other users can use it.

Comment: it still opens recent notification dear

Comment: Are all the notifications coming at the same time?

Comment: If you are getting at the same time then How will it differ based on time? You need to have some specific intervals for notifications.

Comment: i used Math.random() but no progress

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51181/discussion-between-sid-and-dimitri)